# npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

I'm having this famous issue while trying to install Typescript in my react app. Concretely, I am running this: `npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

and I am getting this response:

> npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path
> /mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/node npm ERR!
> dest
> /mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/.node-8MzkXP42
> npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename
> '/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/node' ->
> '/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/.node-8MzkXP42'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename
> '/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/node' ->
> '/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/.node-8MzkXP42']
> { npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!
> syscall: 'rename', npm ERR!   path:
> '/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/node', npm
> ERR!   dest:
> '/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/.node-8MzkXP42'
> npm ERR! } npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your
> operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the
> permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! npm ERR!
> If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check
> the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories,
> or try running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/asier/.npm/_logs/2021-04-29T10_48_16_436Z-debug.log

- I've checked the ownership of that folder: `ls -l/mnt/c/Users/asier/dev/nftgram/web/node_modules/@types/node`, and I am the owner of all the files.
- I've also tried to install it executing `npm set unsafe-perm true`
  but didn't work.
- I've installed npm and node with NVM and I am using Windows 10 with
  Ubuntu on WSL.

npm -v: 7.11.1
node -v: v15.14.0
nvm --version: 0.34.0

The weird thing is that I can install other packages with no issues, I just installed react-hook-form for example.

I don't really know which can be the issue and I would be very happy if you guys can give me a clue!

Thank you beforehand for the help! :)

Comment: Are you on windows ?

Comment: @Blessing yes I am using Windows 10 with a Windows Subsystem for Linux

Answer (score 2):

As I saw an error is related to permission. So you need to execute the command with the help of "sudo" like,

```
sudo npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

Comment: That could be a quick workaround but I don't think that's a good practice

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the way to fix it was to stop my code that was running (webpack serve). In Windows you can't edit/delete files when those are in use. I think wsl may behave the same as it is a linux subsystem "inside" Windows.